# get frame of UIImage in custom UICell use autolayout In iOS8.3

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, autolayout

I have a UIImage in custom UICell.
than I want to get frame of UIImage when custom Cell & UIImage did created.

```
#import "SliderSignInCell.h"
@implementation SliderSignInCell

- (void)layoutSubviews {
  NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromCGRect(self.userImage.frame));
  //    self.userImage.layer.borderWidth = 3.0f;
  //    self.userImage.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
}
```

In iOS8.2 ,I can get frame in layoutSubviews ,after layout completed.
(layoutSubviews run 2 times)

But the same code...

In iOS8.3 ,I can't get frame in layoutSubviews.
(layoutSubviews run 1 times ,when view init)

Log:

In iOS8.2

> 2015-05-20 10:51:20.198 EarlyBee[11989:1914472] {{0, 0}, {240, 128}}.
>
> 2015-05-20 10:51:20.198 EarlyBee[11989:1914472] {{0, 0}, {70, 70}}

In iOS8.3

> 2015-05-20 10:51:20.198 EarlyBee[11989:1914472] {{0, 0}, {240, 128}}

Comment: UImageview frame r8? or UIImage size

Comment: More correctly,
I want to get the moment to hold something ,after self.userImage autolayout

Comment: @JimmyWang I met the the question. What' s your solution at last?

Answer (score 1):

Cannot see anything wrong except one issue: You need to call `[super layoutSubviews]` before do anything else in `-layoutSubviews`:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
  [super layoutSubviews];
  ...
}
```

Comment: It still doesn't work~ Maybe there's  something different in iOS 8.3

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect{
      NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromCGRect(self.userImage.frame));
      self.userImage.layer.cornerRadius = self.userImage.frame.size.width / 2;
      self.userImage.clipsToBounds = YES;
}
```

my solution .

Comment: But...
I don't know why..
In iOS8.2 ,I can get frame in layoutSubviews ,after layout completed. (layoutSubviews run 2 times)

But the same code...

In iOS8.3 ,I can't get frame in layoutSubviews.
(layoutSubviews run 1 times ,when view init)

Comment: However, it's still CGRectZero in my project after overriding it. I crashed